# Using aggregated column in group by statement- MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case, aggregate-functions

Below is the sql query which is throwing error when I use aggregated column in group by statement. Please advise how to do it efficiently in MySQL.

```
   select 
CASE 
  WHEN avg(sm.pace)<0.30 THEN 'Ineligible' 
  WHEN avg(sm.pace)>=0.30 AND avg(sm.pace)<0.40 THEN 'Tier1' 
  WHEN avg(sm.pace)>=0.40 AND avg(sm.pace)<0.50 THEN 'Tier2'
  WHEN avg(sm.pace)>=0.50 AND avg(sm.pace)<0.75 THEN 'Potential'
  WHEN avg(sm.pace)>0.75 THEN 'Inline' END AS Category,
, ROUND(SUM(sm.balance_due),2)
FROM SUMMARY sm
GROUP BY Category
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The query does not make sense.

Comment: As it throws an error, Show the message

Comment: But you are also aggregating in your `case` expression, what should that group by? I know mysql allows it, but the general rule is: when a `group by` is defined, all selected attribute should be either in an aggregation function or in the `group by`. It works the other way as well; if an aggregation function is used, a `group by` has to be defined or it is aggregated over the entire set (and no other attributes can be selected)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear but from what i could see you need to create a function and pass the value sm.pace into it which will use case and return the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you don't really want the `avg()`.  If you want one row per category, this may be what you want:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN sm.pace < 0.30 THEN 'Ineligible' 
             WHEN sm.pace >= 0.30 AND sm.pace < 0.40 THEN 'Tier1' 
             WHEN sm.pace >= 0.40 AND sm.pace < 0.50 THEN 'Tier2'
             WHEN sm.pace >= 0.50 AND sm.pace < 0.75 THEN 'Potential'
             WHEN sm.pace > 0.75 THEN 'Inline'
        END) AS Category,  
       ROUND(SUM(sm.balance_due), 2)
FROM SUMMARY sm
GROUP BY Category;
```

If this what you want, you can simplify the code by taking advantage of the fact that `CASE` statements are evaluated in order:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN sm.pace < 0.30 THEN 'Ineligible' 
             WHEN sm.pace < 0.40 THEN 'Tier1' 
             WHEN sm.pace < 0.50 THEN 'Tier2'
             WHEN sm.pace < 0.75 THEN 'Potential'
             ELSE 'Inline'
        END) AS Category,  
       ROUND(SUM(sm.balance_due), 2)
FROM SUMMARY sm
GROUP BY Category;
```

Note:  This will combine `NULL` values into the `'Inline'` vote, rather than putting them into a `NULL` category.